# how to add new column array in delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, matrix

I want to add some columns after the last one in a matrix of size 10X10. I have wrote the code like below :

```
 for i:=1 to N
      do
    begin
      for j:=1 to N  do
        if j = N then
        begin
         if fileexists('d:\A\'+'img'+inttostr(I)+' '+'0'+'.bmp') then

          Write(f,input^[i]^[j],' ','0')
        end
          else
           Write(f,input^[i]^[j],' ','1');
```

But this code adds columns between other columns. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Are we to assume that `N` is 11 or something?

Comment: If you want to add a column to 10 x 10 matrix, why not making it 10 x 11 matrix ?

Comment: @Hendra, I think the question is about why the code writes columns between columns. The `end` that follows `FileExists` is clearly misplaced and should be moved after the last `Write`. See my answer for more improvments.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are ending your test for `FileExists` earlier than you expect.

This code will write something in the extra column after all fixed columns are written.

```
for i := 1 to N do
begin
  for j := 1 to N do
    Write(f, input^[i]^[j], ' '); 
  // Now it is time for writing the extra column   
  if FileExists('d:\A\' + 'img' + inttostr(i) + ' ' + '0' + '.bmp') then
    WriteLn(f, '0')
  else
    WriteLn(f, '1');
end;
```

Edit: You only need to test for the file once for every index i. Updated code.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, by clicking the check-box at the left, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask